# React Router render above Footer?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

Can I use React Router in my `<Footer/>` to render components in my `<App/>` component inside the `<div>`? Right now, if I add Route to my Footer, the components get rendered either below the footer or right above it, while still beeing part of the footer.

My index.js

```
ReactDOM.render(
  [<Header/>, <App />, <Footer />],
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

My App.js

```
<div className="content"></div>
```

My Footer.js (partly)

```
<footer className="footer">
        <Router>
          <div className="row">
            <div className="column">
              <ul className="no-bullet-list">
                <li>
                  <h2>About us</h2>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <Link to="/whoWeAre" className="text">
                    Who we are
                  </Link>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <Link to="/about" className="text">
                    About
                  </Link>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </div>
              </ul>
            </div>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </div>
          <Route path="/whoWeAre" component={whoWeAre} />
          <Route path="/about" component={about} />
        </Router>
      </footer>

...

function whoWeAre() {
  return <WhoWeAre/>;
}
function about() {
  return <About/>;
}
```

Obviously, this approach renders WhoWeAre and About below my footer. Am I open for any ideas, even it means I have to restructure my index.js and App.js

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest that you add an app layout component.

```
export const AppLayout = ({ children }) => (
  <div className="container">
    <div className="layout">
      <header>...</header>
      <div className="layout__main">
        <main>{children}</main>
      </div>
      <footer>...</footer>
    </div>
  </div>
);
```

Then you can use it like this:

```
 <Router history={createBrowserHistory()}>
      <AppLayout>
         ... your routes here
     </AppLayout>
 </Router>
```

The final result is the following:

- Your app has a global "layout" component
- Inside the layout component you can define header, main section and footer
- Your routes will be rendered as partial views inside the main container
- Your routes will reuse global footer and header